# Teradata - Listing objects involved in a query

Tags: sql, teradata, ddl, sql-tuning

Is there a SQL statement that will let me list out all the objects ( tables views SP's macros ) that are involved in a Teradata SQL Query- much like show select * from WITHOUT expanding their DDL's 
This would be the same as equivalent of what Visual Explain did.

Comment: `SHOW SELECT` is the best you can get.

Comment: Beyond @dnoeth's advice, if you have access to DBQL and object logging is enabled you can get more detail in DBQL. But that may be overkill for the average developer or ad hoc user.

Comment: Ok thank you Learned ppl